# Blazor Request blocked by CORS policy on PHP API

Tags: c#, cors, client, blazor, .net-core-3.0

I am setting up a PHP API and a web-page based on client-side Blazor. But for some reason CORS is triggered and my login process or any requests to my PHP pages result in CORS errors.

I started out testing my PHP API with a C# console app and the Blazor app, I tried using without any database access to test the functionality. The Blazor is right now running with Preview 9. The PHP version is 5.3.8. I could in theory update it, but several other active projects are running on it and I do not have any test environment. MySQL version 5.5.24.

First I figured it might have been because I was running it on my local machine, so I pushed it to the website where the PHP and MySQL is also running. Still I run into this CORS error.

I am still just testing this, so I have tried setting it to allow any origin. I have not had any experience with CORS before this. Pretty sure I ought to be able to add PHP code in each file I access that should allow CORS, but since it should all be on the same website, I figure CORS should not even be relevant?

PHP Code:

```
function cors() {

// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // Decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is one
    // you want to allow, and if so:
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}

echo "You have CORS!";
}
cors();
```

C# code using the injected HttpClient:

```
var resp = await Http.GetStringAsync(link);
```

The error I get is:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://titsam.dk/ntbusit/busitapi/requestLoginToken.php' from origin 'https://www.titsam.dk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The response I hoped to get was that the link I use return a token for the login as it does for my API.

Is it because its running client side maybe and this triggers CORS? But that does not seem to explain why I cannot make it allow all.

Update:
My C# code in OnInitializedAsync:

```
link = API_RequestLoginTokenEndPoint;

Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "basic:testuser:testpass");

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, link);

requestMessage.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
{
    credentials = "include"
};

var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var responseStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

output = responseBody + " " + responseStatusCode;
```

Update 2:
It finally works. The C# code I linked is the solution Agua From Mars suggested and it solved the problem to use SendAsync with a HttpRequestMessage and adding the Fetch property include credentials to it. Another alternative was to add this line to the startup:

```
WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
```

Then I could keep doing what I did to begin with, using GetStringAsync as it becomes the default.
await Http.GetStringAsync(API_RequestLoginTokenEndPoint);

So all the solutions Agua From Mars suggested worked. But I encountered a browser problem, where it kept the CORS issue in the cache somehow even after it had gotten solved, so it seemed like nothing had changed. Some code changes would show a different result, but I guess the CORS part was kept alive. With Chrome it helped opening a new pane or window. In my Opera browser this was not enough, I had to close all panes with the site open to ensure it would clear the cache and then opening a new window or pane with the site works in Opera as well. I had already in both browsers trying to use ctrl-F5 and Shift-F5 to get them to clear the cache. This did not change anything.

I hope this will help others avoid spending 2-3 days on an issue like this.

Comment: You have to allow the origin in the web api that is being called.
Right now it is being blocked because the api server is not allowing the browser to make the api call.

Comment: Do you make a CORS request ? Is your Blazor app and your PHP Web Api  resides on the same domain ? If the answer is yes, then, you're not making   a CORS request. Just ensure whether you're making a CORS request... Why don't you post your C# code here ? Are you sure it's OK ? Please, try to run your app from a different browser, clear cache, etc.

Comment: Same-site means same-site, but you're not really clear about that now. Run it all on LocalHost or specify very exactly.

Comment: The PHP code I linked is set to allow any and all origins and all types.

I linked the specific error message as well. I would argue it IS the same domain and I should not even need CORS.
Access to fetch at 'https://titsam.dk/ntbusit/busitapi/requestLoginToken.php' from origin 'https://www.titsam.dk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: I added my C# code to the original post.

Comment: Seems it might have been a browser cache... something... issue. On top of also being an issue with CORS. But now its working in Chrome in a new pane. For some reason ctrl-F5 and shift-F5 does not seem to really update the cache and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### update 3.1-preview3

In 3.1-preview3, we cannot use the fetch option per message, the options is global

```cs
WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandlerOptions.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
```

`WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler` has been removed. The `HttpMessageHanlder` used is `WebAssembly.Net.Http.HttpClient.WasmHttpMessageHandler` from `WebAssembly.Net.Http` but don't include `WebAssembly.Net.Http` in your depencies or the application will failled to launch.

If you want to use the `HttpClientFactory` you can implement like that :

```cs
public class CustomDelegationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IUserStore _userStore;
    private readonly HttpMessageHandler _innerHanler;
    private readonly MethodInfo _method;

   public CustomDelegationHandler(IUserStore userStore, HttpMessageHandler innerHanler)
   {
       _userStore = userStore ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userStore));
       _innerHanler = innerHanler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerHanler));
       var type = innerHanler.GetType();
       _method = type.GetMethod("SendAsync", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot get SendAsync method");
       WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandlerOptions.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
   }
   protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(_userStore.AuthenticationScheme, _userStore.AccessToken);            
        return _method.Invoke(_innerHanler, new object[] { request, cancellationToken }) as Task<HttpResponseMessage>;
   }
}
```

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient(p =>
    {
        var wasmHttpMessageHandlerType =  Assembly.Load("WebAssembly.Net.Http")
                        .GetType("WebAssembly.Net.Http.HttpClient.WasmHttpMessageHandler");
        var constructor = wasmHttpMessageHandlerType.GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>());
        return constructor.Invoke(Array.Empty<object>()) as HttpMessageHandler;
    })
    .AddTransient<CustomDelegationHandler>()
    .AddHttpClient("MyApiHttpClientName")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustonDelegationHandler>();
}
```

### 3.0 -> 3.1-preview2

On Blazor client side your need to tell to the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send credentials (cookies and authorization header).

It's describe in the **Blazor doc** [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors)

```cs
        requestMessage.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
        { 
            credentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include
        };
```

ex:

```cs
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@inject HttpClient Http

@code {
    private async Task PostRequest()
    {
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "{OAUTH TOKEN}");

        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = new HttpMethod("POST"),
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:10000/api/TodoItems"),
            Content = 
                new StringContent(
                    @"{""name"":""A New Todo Item"",""isComplete"":false}")
        };

        requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(
                "application/json");

        requestMessage.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(
            "x-custom-header", "value");

        requestMessage.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
        { 
            credentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include
        };

        var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        var responseStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

You can set up this option globaly with `WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandlerOptions.DefaultCredentials` static proprerty.

Or you can implement a `DelegatingHandler` and set it up in DI with the HttpClientFactory:

```cs
    public class CustomWebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler : WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler
    {
        internal new Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public class CustomDelegationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly CustomWebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler _innerHandler;

        public CustomDelegationHandler(CustomWebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        {
            _innerHandler = innerHandler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerHandler));
        }
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
            {
                credentials = "include"
            };
            return _innerHandler.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

In `Setup.ConfigureServices`

```cs
services.AddTransient<CustomWebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler>()
    .AddTransient<WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler>()
    .AddTransient<CustomDelegationHandler>()
    .AddHttpClient(httpClientName)
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomDelegationHandler>();
```

Then you can create an `HttpClient` for your API with `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClientName)`

To use the `IHttpClientFactory` you need to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package.

### 3.0-preview3 => 3.0-preview9

Replace `WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler` with `BlazorHttpMessageHandler`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201988/discussion-on-answer-by-agua-from-mars-blazor-request-blocked-by-cors-policy-on).

Comment: That brings me close I think. But I am unsure how to initialize the httpclient in the Startup? I have been wondering where tis coming from when I inject it, I assumed it was built in code somewhere.
The line .AddHttpClient(httpClientName)  needs to refer to a clientname. Not sure how to set or find that client name? Is there some DI defined somewhere else maybe? Same problem with new HttpClient(new CustomDelegationHandler(new CustomWebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler())). Not sure how to set the HttpClient to this client? So far I have used the FetchData example as my blueprint.

Comment: No, you decide what is the http client name for your api.

Comment: Samuel, how do I change my username in the chat? Very confusing having to remember that I am user6830857 with no profile image.

Comment: So I can just use anything as my client name? Dont I have to refer to this name on the Razor page?

Comment: You juste have to reuse the same name when you register your client DI and when you ask to the IHttpClientFactory for a new client

Comment: It... works. Something works. First I was sure it was the new custom httpClient, but... its only working in one browser and only in one pane.

So there is a cache issue on top of the other issues. But other changes did get reflected in the responses.

Thanks for your patience Agua. You have been extremely helpful :) Now I will try to figure out exactly what worked and update my initial post trying to explain what my problem really was, so I can figure out what really made this work. I somewhat suspect it already worked with the initial solution with FetchCredentialsOption.Include

Comment: IMO you should create a new question, don't update this one

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. I wanted to update the question to explain what my problem was, and what solved it, so that others might learn from it. I do not have any new issues or questions. Not yet anyway. I will make a new question if I do come across something else after this, but usually I can google something.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry for that