# Client-side Blazor using SendAsync for a GetRequest with CORS for an API request

Tags: c#, cors, client-side, blazor, webassembly

I ran into some issues with CORS when setting up my Blazor client-side API client to make requests. I think I found the solution to that, but the solution is also throwing errors.

The main error is:
"WASM: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value '2' is not a valid enum value of type RequestCredentials."

the code is

```
        string link = API_RequestLoginTokenEndPoint;

        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "basic:testuser:testpassword");

        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), link);

        requestMessage.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
        {
            credentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include
        };

        var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        var responseStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        output = responseBody + " " + responseStatusCode;
```

I also tried changing the request message to:
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, link);

In case this was the ENUM the error referred to. In the Startup ConfigureServices I tried to add:
WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;

I am using Blazor preview 9. I also tried adding some CORS code to my PHP script on the API route that should accept all origins, but the last question I posted I was told to use this method to fix the CORS problem, which now gives me a new error.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something? The error in the browser usually points to the line with the async request:
var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug not yet fixed. Use this instead :

```cs
requestMessage.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
        {
            credentials = "include"
        };
```

Comment: But I am doing this in the example code.

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), link);

        requestMessage.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
        {
            credentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include
        };

        var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);

But I am still getting the error.

Comment: Oh, wait... its not exactly the same. I will try this.

Comment: That worked... except now I am back to having the original CORS error:

Access to fetch at 'https://titsam.dk/ntbusit/busitapi/requestLoginToken.php' from origin 'https://www.titsam.dk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Check the request header sent by your browser in the browser debug tool and your CORS policy

Comment: I was hoping I had gotten the server ready with the PHP code I linked in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689421/blazor-request-blocked-by-cors-policy-on-php-api/58689718?noredirect=1#comment103688009_58689718

I do not see how I can check the headers in the browsers debug tool?

Comment: For chrome Ctrl + shift + i > Network tab > Click the request > Headers tab > Request headers section

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and could not resolve the pre-flight activity.

****I WAS ABLE TO SOLVE THIS BY COMMENTING OUT HTTP REDIRECTION MIDDLEWARE**.**

context:  Blazor client calls  asp.net.core api in different url.

Not sure if this a good solution but I felt I needed to mention this after
spending 1 week on this frustrating issue! Hope it helps someone.